# AngularJS + RequireJS Module Definitions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a fairly large project that uses both RequireJS and AngularJS.  Everything works fine but looking at my code its kind of a mess with module definitions.  For example here is the 'main' app file:

```
define(['angular',
        'jquery',
        'ui-router',
        'angular-restmod',
        'angular-cookies',
        'angular-animate',
        'angular-sanitize',
        'angular-touch',
        'angular-moment',
        'angular-ui-select2',
        'bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/resizable',
        'bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/draggable',
        'bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/sortable',
        'bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/droppable',
        'angularui',
        'angular-hotkeys',
        'splitter',
        'angular-loading-bar',
        'common/components/chart/chart',
        'common/utils/confirmLeave',
        'common/utils/listener',
        'common/components/toolbar/toolbar',
        'common/components/anchor/anchor',
        'common/utils/print',
        'common/components/notifications/notifications',
        'angular-shims-placeholder'], function (angular, $) {

    var app = angular.module('myapp', ['restmod', 'ngCookies', 'ui.router', 'oc.lazyLoad', 'ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'angularMoment', 
        'ui.bootstrap', ui.select2', 'utils.listener', 'ng.shims.placeholder', 'interceptors.exceptions', 'interceptors.security', 'cfp.hotkeys', 'utils.offline', 'components.notifications', 'angular-loading-bar']);

    return module;

});
```

if you notice I define both the the amd module and the angular module twice.  Its pretty nasty looking ( even though it does work fine ).

My question is has anyone found a better approach for this?  I've seen this [ngDefine](http://nikku.github.io/requirejs-angular-define/) project but I have my reservations about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing my own little utility to handle this...

```
define(['angular'], function(angular){
    angular.defineModule = function dm(name, modules){
       var pargs = dm.caller.arguments;

       var filtered = Array.slice(pargs)
            .filter(function (m) { return m && m.name; })
            .map(function (mm) { return mm.name; });

       modules && (filtered = filtered.concat(modules));

       return angular.module(name, filtered);
   };
});
```

then you can use it like:

```
define(['angular',
        'core',
        'common/services/users',
        'common/services/account',
        'common/components/toolbar/toolbar',
        'common/components/multi-select/multi-select',
        './change-avatar',
        './change-password',
        'less!app/admin/users/detail/detail'], function (angular) {

    var module = angular.defineModule('admin.users.detail');   

    // fun code here //

    return module;

});
```

the caveat is all your require modules have to return the angular module at the end.  If they don't, then I created a 'shim' technique where you can pass it in manually like:

```
var module = angular.defineModule('admin.roles.settings', ['textAngular']);
```

Interested to get others feedback...

Answer (score -1):

You're not loading the modules twice; you are loading the modules once so that it can be found when you declare your application-module's dependencies. As AMD module you depend on them the first time at which time they are physically loaded and as AngularJS module you depend on them but that's only possible when they are already visible.

What we do to cut away some of this boilerplate code is have a generic `core.js` AMD module which loads all the libraries we are going to need always anyway (jquery, plugins, angular etc.). Then our main app file would simply depend on the *core* module.

You can take this further, by defining an AngularJS 'core' module as well. Then all you need is:

```
define(['core'], function (angular, $) {
    return angular.module('myapp', ['core']);
});
```

You moved it out, but also made it reusable over multiple modules for both RequireJS and AngularJS.

Regarding [`ngDefine`](http://nikku.github.io/requirejs-angular-define/), it seems like syntactical sugar. Considering mixing AngularJS with RequireJS already provides the necessary learning curve, alienating the syntax more while not gaining a significant advantage seems like a choice you can skip. Ask yourself: "*Our current approach is ugly, but do I do this a lot? Is it a real problem worth another library and a new way of defining angular apps?*". Probably not!

Comment: I agree on ngDefine syntax sugar ( hints my hesitation ).  I agree your approach would work but my app is designed so that all the modules are broken into separate angular modules too ( see https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide ) so its just not only the third party modules.